# Do free electrons really not interact with photons?

Tags: photons, quantum-electrodynamics, electrons

If free electrons don't interact with photons, why are free electrons accelerated by electromagnetic fields?

Comment: Er...who told you that? Compton scattering, anyone?

Comment: perhaps a more precise statement is that they don't absorb photons?

Comment: Even that calls for some hemming and hawing. They don't absorb real (on-shell) photons, but the effect of the classical field is modeled with the exchange of virtual (off-shell) photons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The laws of conservations of momentum and energy combined forbid the reaction $$e^- + \gamma \rightarrow  e^-$$ 
(Go ahead and do the math, is simple and enlightnening).

But a completely different story is:

$$e^- + \gamma \rightarrow  e^- + \gamma$$

Where the incoming photon has a different energy that the outcoming one.

And also, you can have an absortion by an atom $X$:

$$X + \gamma \rightarrow X$$

Or emission by some nuclei:

$$ {}^{60}Co \rightarrow {}^{60}Co + \gamma $$

The reason for it is that, unlike an elementary particle, the atom and the nucleus have internal degrees of freedom, can store internal energy, but an electron is always an electron.

Comment: Already no need to do the calculus for e^− + γ → e^−. See my answer to the question "Can we find the definite path of electron?", the calculus is there.

Answer (score -3):

Electron accelerators work the way that photons gave to the electrons some amount of their energy. In my understanding this are free electrons. And as long as the electrons could be accelerated more of the energy from the photons will be absorpt then emitted by the electrons.